# How to iterate hain array dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, dynamic

I need to iterate array dynamically.

```
//Function call
validateJsonArray(deptJson, "deptId", "deptValue");

function validateJsonArray(inputArray, objectId, objectValue){

for(int i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++){
    var selectedObjectId=inputArray[i].objectId;
.   Var  selectedObjectValue=inputArray[i].objectValue;
}
```

The above code gets selectedObjectId and selectedObjectValue as **undefined**

Comment: `inputArray[i].objectId` should be `inputArray[i][objectId]`

Comment: Thank you @Barmar